# Why is every nonarchimedean local field of characteristic zero a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero that is complete with respect to the multiplicative valuation $|\cdot|:K \to \mathbb{R}$. Also assume that this multiplicative valuation is **nonarchimedean**, that is,
$$
|x+y| \le \max\{|x|,|y|\}
$$
This valuation induces a metric topology on $K$, and we also assume that $K$ is locally compact. I understand the following: $K$ must contain (an isomorphic copy of) $\mathbb{Q}$, and the restriction of the valuation to $\mathbb{Q}$ must be $|\cdot|_p$ for some $p$ (by Ostrowski's theorem), and the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $K$ must be $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

The only assertion left is to say that $[K:\mathbb{Q}_p] < \infty$. According to Milne, "If $K$ has infinite degree over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, it will not be localy compact." Can someone explain why this is true?

Comment: It follows from Krasner's lemma. See [this](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/cheltsov/gnt/hw4.pdf) for example.

Comment: @Mathmo123 the link doesn't work anymore. Could you please give some other reference or an hint of how the proof works?

Comment: Btw I've now managed to download the PDF but this does not esclude the case where the extension Is not algebraic. Maybe It Is trivial but I've not managed to exclude It. If you have any hint about It please tell me.

Answer (score 8):

A comment above suggests using Krasner's lemma to explain the finite-dimensionality. I will describe a more constructive argument, which is similar to what can be found in Gouvea's book on $p$-adic numbers when he works out $\pi$-adic expansions of finite extensions of $\mathbf Q_p$, but here I will be starting from a local compactness assumption instead of a finite-dimensionality assumption.

1. Local compactness of $K$ implies compactness of its ring of integers $\mathcal O_K =\{x \in K : |x| < 1\}$ by a scaling argument (here we rely on nontriviality of the absolute value on $K$, a consequence of its local compactness and it being infinite). Therefore every subsequence of $\mathcal O_K$ has a convergent subsequence.
2. ("discreteness of absolute value") There is a nonzero $\pi \in K$ making $|\pi|$ the biggest absolute value less than 1: $|\pi| = \max\{|x| : |x| < 1\}$.  Indeed, if there are no such maximum then there is an increasing sequence of absolute values $|x_1| < |x_2| < \ldots < 1$ and the sequence $\{x_i\}$ has no convergent subsequence (a sequence with a nonzero limit must have eventually constant absolute value but all the $x_i$'s have distinct absolute values).
3. ("ramification index") By item 2, $|K^\times| = |\pi|^\mathbf Z$. Therefore $|p| = |\pi|^e$ for some $e \in \mathbf Z$. Since $|p| < 1$ and $|\pi| < 1$, $e \in \mathbf Z^+$. Then  $[|K^\times|:|\mathbf Q_p^\times|] = [|\pi|^{\mathbf Z}:|\pi|^{e\mathbf Z}] = e$, so we have an interpretation of $e$ as an index of value groups.
4. ("residue field degree") The residue field $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m_K = \mathcal O_K/\pi\mathcal O_K$ has to be finite, since representatives for the residue field in $\mathcal O_K$ are all at distance 1 from each other and therefore wouldn't have a convergent subsequence if it were infinite. This residue field contains $\mathbf F_p$, so we have a finite residue field degree $f = \dim_{\mathbf F_p}(\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak m_K)$.
5. ("some $\pi$-adic expansion") Let $S$ be a set of representatives for the residue field, with $0$ representing the zero element of the residue field, so $S$ contains $p^f$ elements. In the same way $p$-adic expansions in $\mathbf Z_p$ can be developed from the representatives $\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ of the residue field of $\mathbf Q_p$, and they are unique, every element of $\mathcal O_K$ has a unique $\pi$-adic expansion $\sum_{j \geq 0} s_j\pi^j$ with $s_j \in S$ (uniqueness uses $0 \in S$). For nonzero $x \in K$, $|x| = |\pi|^n$ for some $n \in \mathbf Z$ (possibly $n < 0$), so $|x/\pi^n| = 1$. Then writing the $\pi$-adic expansion of $x/\pi^n$ and multiplying through by $\pi^n$ afterwards, each nonzero element of $K$ has a (unique) $\pi$-adic expansion $\sum_{j \geq n} s_j\pi^j$ with $s_n \not= 0$.
6. ("good choices") Lift a basis of the residue field over $\mathbf F_p$ into $\mathcal O_K$: there is a set $\{b_1,\ldots,b_f\}$ in $\mathcal O_K$ such that they reduce modulo $\mathfrak m_K$ to an $\mathbf F_p$-basis of the residue field. We can use as $S$ the set of linear combinations $\{a_1b_1 + \cdots + a_fb_f : a_i \in \{0,\ldots,p-1\}\}$. In the $\pi$-adic expansions of step 5, we don't need to use the powers $\pi^j$ to represent all nonzero absolute values: write an integer $j$ as $eq+r$ with $q \in \mathbf Z$ and $0 \leq r \leq e-1$, so $|\pi|^j = |\pi|^{eq+r} = |\pi|^{eq}|\pi^r| = |p^q\pi^r|$. Therefore we can use the numbers $p^q\pi^r$ to represent all nonzero absolute values in $K$, with $|p^q\pi^r| \leq 1$ if and only if $q \geq 0$ and $r \geq 0$.
7. ("basis over $\mathbf Q_p$") Using step 6, each element of $\mathcal O_K$ can be written as a series $\sum_{q \geq 0} \sum_{r=0}^{e-1} s_{qr}p^{q}\pi^r$ where $s_{qr} = a_{1qr}b_1 + \cdots + a_{fqr}b_f$ for some $a_{iqr} \in \{0,\ldots,p-1\}$. Thus each element of $\mathcal O_K$ has the form 
   $$
   \sum_{q \geq 0} \sum_{r=0}^{e-1} \sum_{i=1}^f a_{iqr}b_ip^{q}\pi^r = 
   \sum_{r=0}^{e-1} \sum_{i=1}^f\left(\sum_{q \geq 0} a_{iqr}p^{q}\right)b_i\pi^r =
   \sum_{r=0}^{e-1} \sum_{i=1}^fc_{ir}b_i\pi^r
   $$
   where $c_{ir} = \sum_{q \geq 0} a_{iqr}p^{q}$ is a $p$-adic integer: $c_{ir} \in \mathbf Z_p$.  For nonzero $x \in K$, $|p^Nx| < 1$ for some (large) integer $N$, so we can write $p^Nx$ in the above form and then divide by $p^N$, absorbing that $p^N$ into the coefficients $c_{ir}$ to make them lie in $\mathbf Q_p$ (possibly no longer $\mathbf Z_p$).  Thus each element of $K$ can be written as a $\mathbf Q_p$-linear combination of the finite set $\{b_i\pi^r : 1 \leq i \leq f, 0 \leq r \leq e-1\}$, which proves $K$ is finite-dimensional over $\mathbf Q_p$ with dimension at most $ef$. In fact, that finite set is linearly independent over $\mathbf Q_p$, so $[K:\mathbf Q_p] = ef$, which is no surprise ("$n=ef$").